# TDs mixed into one big column in an HTML Email

Tags: outlook, html-email

I am using an html table in an html based email. The table displays correctly if the number of columns in the email are less than 68. But if the number of columns are more than that then the remaining columns are mixed into 68th column in an outlook email.
Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

The HTML code is:

```
<table border=1>
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
<th colspan="5">Header1</th>
<th colspan="5">Header2</th>
<th colspan="5">Header3</th>
<th colspan="5">Header4</th>
<th colspan="5">Header5</th>
<th colspan="5">Header6</th>
<th colspan="5">Header7</th>
<th colspan="5">Header8</th>
<th colspan="5">Header9</th>
<th colspan="5">Header10</th>
<th colspan="5">Header11</th>
<th colspan="5">Header12</th>
<th colspan="5">Header13</th>
<th colspan="5">Header14</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="headerRow">
<td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
<td>SubCol1</td>
<td>SubCol2</td>
<td>SubCol3</td>
<td>SubCol4</td>
<td>SubCol5</td>
<td>SubCol1</td>
<td>SubCol2</td>
<td>SubCol3</td>
<td>SubCol4</td>
<td>SubCol5</td>
<td>SubCol1</td>
<td>SubCol2</td>
<td>SubCol3</td>
<td>SubCol4</td>
<td>SubCol5</td>
<td>SubCol1</td>
<td>SubCol2</td>
<td>SubCol3</td>
<td>SubCol4</td>
<td>SubCol5</td>
<td>SubCol1</td>
<td>SubCol2</td>
<td>SubCol3</td>
<td>SubCol4</td>
<td>SubCol5</td>
<td>SubCol1</td>
<td>SubCol2</td>
<td>SubCol3</td>
<td>SubCol4</td>
<td>SubCol5</td>
<td>SubCol1</td>
<td>SubCol2</td>
<td>SubCol3</td>
<td>SubCol4</td>
<td>SubCol5</td>
<td>SubCol1</td>
<td>SubCol2</td>
<td>SubCol3</td>
<td>SubCol4</td>
<td>SubCol5</td>
<td>SubCol1</td>
<td>SubCol2</td>
<td>SubCol3</td>
<td>SubCol4</td>
<td>SubCol5</td>
<td>SubCol1</td>
<td>SubCol2</td>
<td>SubCol3</td>
<td>SubCol4</td>
<td>SubCol5</td>
<td>SubCol1</td>
<td>SubCol2</td>
<td>SubCol3</td>
<td>SubCol4</td>
<td>SubCol5</td>
<td>SubCol1</td>
<td>SubCol2</td>
<td>SubCol3</td>
<td>SubCol4</td>
<td>SubCol5</td>
<td>SubCol1</td>
<td>SubCol2</td>
<td>SubCol3</td>
<td>SubCol4</td>
<td>SubCol5</td>
<td>SubCol1</td>
<td>SubCol2</td>
<td>SubCol3</td>
<td>SubCol4</td>
<td>SubCol5</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td>Channel</td>
<td>Grouping</td>
<td>Level</td>
<td colspan="70">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr class="dataRow" > 
<td>Header1</td>
<td>Positive</td>
<td>Different LF</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

The html appears in Chrome as:

[image]

The html appears in email as given below. Notice that columns under Header 13 and 14 are joined into one big column in the email version. Please note that when I reduce the number of column, it start appearing correctly in the email version. Do html tables in emails have any columns limit?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I see with this:

1. No email client will safely or appropriately render that many cells. It's way too long and it's wider than the majority of emails clients can handle in their preview windows.
2. I don't think tables are being used in the most appropriate way to display your information. Whether it be changing the layout you're using to be more vertical, using another format to display this information or just not using tables at all and going for another simplified approach.

I'll leave point 2 up to you to think over but here is what I'd do to simplify the structure of your tables and potentially avoid the issues you're seeing.

```html
<table border=1>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr class="even">
            <td>Channel</td>
            <td>Grouping</td>
            <td>Level</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="even">
            <td>Header1</td>
            <td>Positive</td>
            <td>Different LF</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Header1</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>SubCol1</td><td>SubCol2</td><td>SubCol3</td><td>SubCol4</td><td>SubCol5</td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Header2</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>SubCol1</td><td>SubCol2</td><td>SubCol3</td><td>SubCol4</td><td>SubCol5</td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Header3</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>SubCol1</td><td>SubCol2</td><td>SubCol3</td><td>SubCol4</td><td>SubCol5</td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Header4</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>SubCol1</td><td>SubCol2</td><td>SubCol3</td><td>SubCol4</td><td>SubCol5</td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Header5</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>SubCol1</td><td>SubCol2</td><td>SubCol3</td><td>SubCol4</td><td>SubCol5</td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Header6</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>SubCol1</td><td>SubCol2</td><td>SubCol3</td><td>SubCol4</td><td>SubCol5</td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Header7</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>SubCol1</td><td>SubCol2</td><td>SubCol3</td><td>SubCol4</td><td>SubCol5</td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Header8</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>SubCol1</td><td>SubCol2</td><td>SubCol3</td><td>SubCol4</td><td>SubCol5</td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Header9</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>SubCol1</td><td>SubCol2</td><td>SubCol3</td><td>SubCol4</td><td>SubCol5</td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Header10</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>SubCol1</td><td>SubCol2</td><td>SubCol3</td><td>SubCol4</td><td>SubCol5</td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Header11</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>SubCol1</td><td>SubCol2</td><td>SubCol3</td><td>SubCol4</td><td>SubCol5</td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Header12</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>SubCol1</td><td>SubCol2</td><td>SubCol3</td><td>SubCol4</td><td>SubCol5</td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Header13</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>SubCol1</td><td>SubCol2</td><td>SubCol3</td><td>SubCol4</td><td>SubCol5</td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Header14</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td>SubCol1</td><td>SubCol2</td><td>SubCol3</td><td>SubCol4</td><td>SubCol5</td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table
```